# how to randomly spawn/instantiate an object everywhere in game? c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I'am to trying to practice in making a catch an object game in 2D c#, where I want to catch falling objects with my player object. So what I did is created an Empty GameObject and add a script to it that can spawn a falling object, problem is I don't know how to spawn it in a random place in every 2 - 3 seconds or so.

so here is my code and game view.

```
public class spawnball : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject ballprefab;
GameObject ballclone;




// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {

        spawn ();
        Destroy (ballclone,3);

    }
}

void spawn()
{
    ballclone = Instantiate (ballprefab,transform.position,Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
}


}
```

above the line where I want it to randomly spawn

[image: above the line where I want it to randomly spawn]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the basic idea so far.

The first step is to start using [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) so you can work out how long has it been since last time we spawned a ball.

An example would be:

```
private timeSinceLastDrop: float;
private dropInterval: float = 3f;

void Update(){
    // have we surpassed our interval?
    if(timeSinceLastDrop >= dropInterval){
       this.spawn();
       timeSinceLastDrop = 0;
    }
    else
       timeSinceLastDrop += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

To meet the second issue of where to drop, you can use [`Random.Range(min, max)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) and then use min and max as the outermost parameters you can drop.

For example:

```
void spawn(){
    ballclone = Instantiate(ballprefab,transform.position,Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
    ballclone.transform.position.x +=  Random.Range(-10f, 10f);
}
```

---

I wrote this without an IDE so there may be a syntax error in there somewhere.

Comment: Only thing to note is that the code here uses UnityScript not C#, some minor conversion is required (variable declarations). Otherwise it looks like it'll compile.

Comment: @Draco18s I 100% agree with you, I honestly just assume that when people tag C# for unity they mean unityscript.

Comment: Unity compiles for both (and Boo, but lets be honest, no one uses Boo) so that assumption might not be true.